# postgis distance between two points on a line

Tags: line, distance, postgis, point

I have a route (as a LINESTRING) and two vehicles with a position (as a POINT). I need to calculate the distance between the two points *over* the route.

As an added difficulty I think I also need to measure the distance from the point to the closest point on the line in the case that the vehicle is not on the route at that moment.

I'm using this to find the closest point on the route:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_ClosestPoint(pt,line)) AS cp_pt_line, 
    ST_AsText(ST_ClosestPoint(line,pt)) As cp_line_pt
FROM (SELECT 'POINT(100 100)'::geometry As pt, 
    'LINESTRING (20 80, 98 190, 110 180, 50 75 )'::geometry As line
) As foo;
```

Is that possible in a query?

Comment: are you saying, you have one route (a linestring), two vehicles (two points) and you want to snap each point to the linestring and then find the distance between them along the linestring?

Comment: Yes, that's right. :)
I've found an answer, see below.

Comment: In nowadays, 2018, there are other functions to this task: see also *ST_LineLocatePoint* and *ST_Line_Interpolate_Point*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT     ST_Length(ST_GeographyFromText(ST_AsText(ST_Line_Substring(line,ST_Line_Locate_Point(line,ST_ClosestPoint(line,fpt)),ST_Line_Locate_Point(line,ST_ClosestPoint(line,tpt)))))) As length_m,
                                                                   ST_Distance(ST_ClosestPoint(line,tpt)::geography, tpt::geography) as to_point_to_line_m,
                                                                   ST_Distance(ST_ClosestPoint(line,fpt)::geography, fpt::geography) as from_point_to_line_m,
                                                                   ST_AsText(ST_ClosestPoint(line,tpt)) as to_point_on_line,
                                                                   ST_AsText(ST_ClosestPoint(line,fpt)) as from_point_on_line,
                                                                   ST_AsText(tpt) as to_point,
                                                                   ST_AsText(fpt) as from_point
                                           FROM ( SELECT 'SRID=4326;POINT(1)'::geometry As tpt,
                                                                                          'SRID=4326;POINT(2)'::geometry As fpt,
                                                                                          ST_Segmentize('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(123)'::geometry,  0.00001) As line
                                                       ) As foo;
```

Distance length_m, distance to_point_on_line and from_point_on_line.
:)

Comment: Well done. I was going to tell you about st_line_locate_point, but you have found it yourself, which is better.

Comment: This is an old abandoned question... A solution with [ST_LineLocatePoint()](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineLocatePoint.html) is better. If you upvote here I post the solution.